# Getting recaptcha result from ebay sold page scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, ebay-api

I'm trying to get some information from the total sold page of an item in ebay (because the API request for that is not available anymore).
I've tried both bs4 (beautiful soup) and selenium, but getting recaptcha result and not the page's content itself.
Any help with that issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla Selenium generally leads to CAPTCHA / blocks due to the browser not hiding its identity as a browser automation.

I suggest trying out `undetected_chromedriver` - a slightly modified version of Selenium that circumvents most automated bot-detection protocols.

From the project's description:

> [undetected_chromedriver is an...] optimized Selenium Chromedriver patch which does not trigger anti-bot services like Distill Network / Imperva / DataDome / Botprotect.io

I've used it quite a bit and it almost always works exactly as intended.

**Here's some code to get you started:**

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

# ADD CHROME OPTION -> DISABLE POPUP BLOCKING
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://amazon.com/')
```

You can visit the [project's GitHub](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) for more information. Keep in mind that you'll need to use slightly different syntax vis-a-vis regular Selenium when using certain functions.

Also, you don't need to download chromedriver.exe, as the module automatically downloads the latest version.